# Pausar programa com Timer

Tags: java

Preciso usar ele para esperar *2* minutos antes de executar um método. Já pesquisei e não consigo achar nada claro o suficiente para me ajudar.

Já usei o `Thread.sleep()` mais ele trava a *thread* toda, e não é isso que eu busco.
Obrigado aos que ajudarem.

Answer (score 3):

Isso dever ser simples.

```
Timer timer;

public Executar(int segundos) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MinhaFuncao(), segundos*1000);
}

class MinhaFuncao extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //faz tudo que precisa fazer aqui
        timer.cancel(); //Termina a task
    }
}
```

Dai você chama o executar passando 120 segundos para o método.

**OBS:** esse exemplo utiliza o timer da java.util.Timer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Se você for usar o javax.swing.Timer doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Então você deve fazer assim

```
Timer timer;

int delay = 120*1000; //2 minutos

ActionListener tarefaAgendada = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //faz o que tem que fazer
    }
};

timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
timer.setRepeats(false); //faz rodar apenas 1 vez, sem isso ele ficar invocando a action de 2 em 2 minutos
timer.start(); //inicia a task
```

Comment: O construtor timer pede 2 parâmetros aqui. Um inteiro e um ActionListener. Consequentemente o código nem rodou.

Comment: @Higor esta usando o timer da  java.util.Timer ?

Comment: @Higor veja minha edição na resposta

Comment: Eu estava usando Timer da java.swing.Timer, troquei e consegui usar aqui. Obrigado, abraços.

Comment: @Higor fico feliz que solucionou seu problema. Lembre-se de marcar a resposta como correta para ajudar outros usuários que possam ter a mesma dúvida que você.